# App works fine in browser but not with cordova

Tags: cordova, requirejs

I'm using Cordova 6 and Requirejs for my application. When i launch my app into the iPhone emulator the cordova deviceready event gets fired but my code that is loaded via require js never gets called :(

I load cordova before own code an wait for the deviceready event to fire:

```
document.addEventListener('deviceready', function() {
    alert('this gets called with cordova so we know this works')
    define('app', ['router'], function(Router) {
        alert('in regular browser i get called, but not in cordova')
    });
}, false);
```

Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: Maybe this is the problem? http://www.adamauckland.com/posts/cordovaphonegap-and-requirejs-on-windows-phone-8/

But there must be other people that use requirejs and cordova together right?

Comment: In a normal browser window like Google Chrome or Safari the application runs just fine, it only occurs when i enable the cordova.js to load.

Answer (score 1):

Something that result for me was removing data-main attribute from require and load my main javascript file directly, then after deviceReady event fires use require as normal

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/libs/require/require.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="app/init.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

```js
var app = {

  initialize: function() {
    document.addEventListener('deviceready', this.onDeviceReady, false);
  },

  onDeviceReady: function() {
    require(['app/requireModuleConfig'], function() {
      require([
          'core/shell',
          'domReady!'
        ],
        function(shell) {
          ko.applyBindings(shell);
          shell.Init();
        });
    });
  }
};

app.initialize();
```

requireModuleConfig.js

```js
requirejs.config({

    baseUrl: window.location.pathname.replace('shell.html', '') + 'app/',
    //baseUrl: 'http://localhost:3001/app/',
    paths: {
        lib: '../js/libs',
        styles: '../content',
        text: '../js/libs/require/text',
        css: '../js/libs/require/css',
        domReady: '../js/libs/require/domReady',
        baseProxy: 'core/proxies/baseProxy',
        logger: '../js/libs/toastr/logger/logger',
        appContext: 'core/appContext',
        sync: 'core/sync/syncEngine',
        constants: 'core/constants/constants'
    },
    config: {
        text: {
            useXhr: function (url, protocol, hostname, port) {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Did you have the same problem is me? Thank you for our answer.

Comment: Not exactly the same problem but similar, my problem was that I was losing result intents on android devices just because I load everything using require.

Something different is that I'm using require instead of define, and my the first thing that I do is load require config.

Comment: And what does your config look like? I tried this but now i get Mismatched anonymous define() errors.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry can't comment yet. But I did the same thing-ish and it fixed a very similar problem.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="libs/require.js"></script>
<script>
    document.addEventListener('deviceready', function() {
        require.config({
            baseUrl: 'js',
            paths: {
                handlebars: "../lib/handlebars/handlebars",
                text: "../lib/text/text",
                i18n: "../lib/i18n/i18n",
                hbs: "../lib/requirejs-hbs/hbs",
                moment: "../lib/moment/moment",
                moment_fr: "../lib/moment/locale/fr",
                moment_duration: "../lib/moment-duration-format/lib/moment-duration-format"
            },
            shim: {
                handlebars: {
                    exports: "Handlebars"
                }
            },
            config: {
                moment: {
                    noGlobal: true
                },
                i18n: {
                    locale: localStorage.getItem('locale') || 'en'
                }
            }
        });
        require(['init'], function(init) {
            init.coreApp();
        });
    }, false);

</script>
```